# Is possible position multiple elements in grid cell as one element without a container wrapping them?

Tags: html, css

I'm making html layout which will be showing shop receipt, i need it to be unified so i can style design of different shops receipts only with use of css maybe java-script if it would help.

So far most likely option come css grid, because my html layout is fixed and cannot be modified in advance to adding new receipts styles. I had done grid container which includes three containers. Those containers contain divs with data from database. I can control appearance of divs with display: none and position in grid with grid-area property.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item1">Pr: </div>
    <div class="item2">Levocska</div>
    <div class="item3">tel: </div>
    <div class="item4">0900 000 000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  "one"
  "two";
  background-color: yellow;
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: one;
  background-color: red;
  width: 125px;
  text-align: right;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: one;
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 168px;
  justify-self: end;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: two;
  background-color: red;
  width: 112px;
  text-align: right;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: two;
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 180px;
  justify-self: end;
}
```

Here come problem, sometimes i need place two div elements in one grid cell but then because there is no flow in grid cell they overlap. Is there any option how i can control and position those two elements as one element ? I cannot wrap them because of unification for multiple receipts styles. So far only solution seems to be to use width for element and then text-align and flex to somehow position them but for example centering of two elements cannot be done precise. here is JSFiddle with code https://jsfiddle.net/g8vwby6u/1/ Or is there different approach to solve this issue?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/5en74tLy/ ?

Comment: that unfortunately doesn't solve my problem, as you can see you just split grid into two columns and because content in cells is't equal it is not centered :(

Comment: can you add an image that represents the requirement? I'm a bit confused

Comment: No...because grid-cells are not elements they cannot be selected and thus they cannot be **styled**.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so but was not sure, but thanks guys for response, i will style (position) elements as they overlap and move them left and right where i need them, maybe not so elegant but good enough for i need